# Can baby villagers grow when they are in minecarts?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I built a villager breeder in Minecraft 1.16. The baby villagers flow to a collection station where I wait for them to grow up. When they grow up, it becomes a hassle to put them into minecarts and transport them to a designated location. To bypass the issue, I want to put the baby villagers in a minecart. However, I'm wondering if the villagers grow when they are stuck in a minecart.

Answer (score 1):

They do grow up in 20 minutes in a minecart.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. They can grow in minecarts.

Comment: Could you add some evidence or explanations of that?

Comment: I will wait for the next answer. This doesn't seem detailed enough.

Answer (score 0):

They will grow up in minecarts, I've been doing this a while ago and they grow in minecarts in 1.16.3 as well, they will take 20 minutes exactly to grow and that doesn't depend on where the baby villager is

Comment: In Bedrock or Java Edition? This question is for Bedrock Edition.

Answer (score -2):

No. Unfortunately, I don't have any information to back this up. But I have tried this same thing And the villager doesn't grow while in a minecart. So no.